# How can I find a deregistered airplane?

Tags: aviation-history, usa

I'm trying to find a 1959 C172 tail number N7393T.

It was my grandfather's and the last registered record of it was near Glendale AZ.  It was deregistered in 2015 and I found out that since it cannot be reregistered for 5 years it may have a new tail number. Any tips on tracking and finding this plane would be helpful.

Comment: A quick search on my favorite search engine orient me to [flight aware](https://flightaware.com/resources/registration/N7393T). Then I tried to put the serial number on the [FAA registry](https://registry.faa.gov/aircraftinquiry/Serial_Results.aspx?serialtxt=46993+&sort_option=1&PageNo=1) but without luck. I cannot find any references to this serial number after 2015. What other methods did you tried before asking your question?

Comment: Here’s a helpful link : https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/102715/70478

Answer (score 2):

Sorry to be the bearer of bad news. But, you have already asked this question on [www.airport-data.com](https://www.airport-data.com/forums/post-23777.html). A quick search in the [FAA search database](https://registry.faa.gov/aircraftinquiry/) with the tail number or serial number (which can be found using the tail number) shows that it has not legally flown in the US in almost a decade. So, it is either sitting somewhere as a ramp queen, registered overseas, or not in existence any longer.

Try contacting the last person to register it. Otherwise, it would be like trying to find a salvaged car after it has been junked. It will only pop up if it is reregistered. However, you can pay a private firm like a law firm to research the aircraft’s certificate of title (or simply title). It would be like searching a deed.

Comment: Thanks>  yeah I was trying a couple different forums to expand my search but thanks for the help.  I've tracked it so far to Glendale AZ.  I'll hopefully find it

Comment: @MichaelMatt - I wish you the best of luck in finally finding it. Post an answer with a picture of it when you do. Maybe a description of how you were able to locate it, too.

Answer (score 0):

You could try a search at Landings.com.

They have a serial number search link.

http://www.landings.com/evird.acgi$pass*193800885!_h-www.landings.com/_landings/pages/search.html