# 1959 C172 N7393T is on AviationDatabase, can someone post this please?

Tags: tail

A user named Michael Matt asked about his grandfather's plane:
"I'm trying to find a 1959 C172 tail number N7393T"

I signed up to tell him I believe I found it on on AviationDatabase, but apparently, I don't have enough credibility to answer. Would someone be so kind as to post the link for him:

https://aviationdb.net/aviationdb/AircraftDetailPage#SUBMIT

His original post is here:
[How can I find a deregistered airplane?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/80562/how-can-i-find-a-deregistered-airplane)

He hasn't been active since he asked, but maybe it will notify him.

Thank you.

Comment: You may have tried to answer in comments.  Comments require a certain reputation, you build reputation points based on upvotes for questions and answers.  So quickly, before anybody downvotes you on this one, maybe try again, ensuring you post an answer in the answer block?  Good work by the way, if it answers the question you have my upvote. This "question" however, will likely be voted closed. Starting with me...

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it isn't a freestanding question, it is phrased as a request regarding another post.

Comment: But if you cannot for some reason, let me know in comments and I will gladly post it as an answer, because I tried and it looks like it works.  Hoping that if you want to continue here you can get credit for the answer...

Comment: Hello Hollis Natalie, welcome to aviation.stackexchange.com! You should be able to post this as an answer under the original question. Scroll all the way down  past the other answers and you'll find an editor box to compose the answer. Unfortunately we don't have the tools to convert this question post into an answer to the original question; you will have to repost it there.